# Intellij 14.1.1 Change Workspace Language

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running Intellij 14.1.1 on OSX, and I do have the PHP plugin installed. I tried to import from source control (GIT) a java project, but it keeps registering it as a php project. At this point, I can't seem to add any java files unless I add file, and my classes show up as using a red icon instead of the blue 'C' class icon.

How do I configure Intellij to stop doing this without uninstalling the PHP Plugin?

Comment: Check the SDKs available in your project.

Comment: Looks like 1.8.0_25 is available, and selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a source root configured in your module. You can configure it in the File | Project Structure dialog.

Comment: Here I was expecting it to be more complicated than that. Thanks!!